# How to use hammer.js with Angular.js

Tags: touch, angularjs, hammer.js

I'm new with [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org) and reading i know angular dont have events like tap, double tap, etc. I'm trying to combine with [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) without success.

Code from [gist](https://gist.github.com/3298323)

```
/**
 * angular-hammer.js
 * Inspired by AngularJS' implementation of "click dblclick mousedown..." 
 *
 * This ties in the Hammer events to attributes like:
 * 
 *   hm-tap="add_something()"
 *   hm-swipe="remove_something()"
 *
 * and also has support for Hammer options with:
 *
 *  hm-tap-opts="{hold: false}"
 *
 * or any other of the "hm-event" listed underneath.
 */
angular.forEach('hmTap:tap hmDoubletap:doubletap hmHold:hold hmTransformstart:transformstart hmTransform:transform hmTransforend:transformend hmDragstart:dragstart hmDrag:drag hmDragend:dragend hmSwipe:swipe hmRelease:release'.split(' '), function(name) {
  var directive = name.split(':');
  var directiveName = directive[0];
  var eventName = directive[1];
  angular.module('MYMODULE').directive(directiveName, 
  ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
      var opts = $parse(attr[directiveName + 'Opts'])(scope, {});
      element.hammer(opts).bind(eventName, function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          console.log("Doing stuff", event);
          fn(scope, {$event: event});
        });
      });
    };
  }]);
});
```

now i've added to my html file

```
<!--...-->
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-hammer.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/app/controllers.js"></script>
</html>
```

But when i try to use in my html it doesn't work.

I've tried with

```
<li hmTap="click($event)">...</li>
<li ngTap="click($event)">...</li>
<li hm-tap="click($event)">...</li>
<li ng-tap="click($event)">...</li>
```

no one works, can help me with this trouble?

Comment: See http://goodfil.ms/blog/posts/2012/08/13/angularjs-and-the-goodfilms-mobile-site-part-1/ for how to create an Angular directive that supports tap events.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Give this a go.

Add hammer.js and jquery.hammer.js to your solution. With JQuery and Angular.

Something like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hammer/hammer.js"></script>
<script src="js/hammer/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[Then use Angular directives to define new HTML attributes.](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

In this example I am creating a new attribute called **`on-tap`**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
       .directive('onTap', function () {
         return function (scope, element, attrs) {
           return $(element).hammer({
             prevent_default: false,
             drag_vertical: false
           })
             .bind("tap", function (ev) {
               return scope.$apply(attrs['onTap']);
             });
         };
       });
```

You can then create a directive per Hammer event:

hold, tap, doubletap, transformstart, transform, transformend, dragstart, drag, dragend, release, swipe.

Your HTML would then look like this:

```
<button on-tap="DoAngularMethod()">Tap me</button>
```

Comment: I believe the AngularJS touch library either uses Hammer or copies how it works, with a variety of events you can bind to on elements (within directives). Might be something to take a look at....

Answer (score 9):

Here is exactly what are  you looking for:
https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures

this new libary allows you to implement all of gestures you need.
also read this:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-on-mobile.html

Hope you find it interesting.
:)

Answer (score 8):

There are some hammer directive implementations for Angular you could try to use:

https://github.com/randallb/angular-hammer

https://github.com/dreame4/angular-hammer

Answer (score 0):

I used *randallb* lib and i added

```
'hmPan:pan',
'hmPanLeft:panleft',
'hmPanRight:panright',
```

in the hmGestures array, so i can use pan too!