# Angularjs with hammer.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, hammer.js

How to implement tap, with angularjs.

This is my example

```
<div ng-click="test">Test</div>
```

I would want to have a tap in place of ng-click. There was one example in this link
[How to use hammer.js with Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432799/how-to-use-hammer-js-with-angular-js)

I was able to bind a tap even in directive this way

```
$(element).hammer({prevent_default: false,drag_vertical: false}).bind("tap",function($event){});
```

But how to replace ng-click or use other events of hammer.js.

Comment: Have you tried looking at angular-gestures? I've only used it for swipe events but seems to work well and is based on hammer.js: https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures

Comment: There also another library which is possibly more up-to-date: http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/. I haven't tried this one yet but intend to take a closer look.